# notification when window is closed

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility

There is the kAXWindowCreatedNotification notification when a window is created but I am looking for the same thing when a window is closed.

Any pointer?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Have you tried `kAXUIElementDestroyedNotification`?

Comment: This is probably the best way. I have to test. Thanks

Comment: Using kAX-constants (assistive) anything is going to require the user to opt-in to Universal Access, yes?

Answer (score -1):

The closest I can think of is `NSWindowWillCloseNotification`.